# Why do phone games limit turns?

Tags: ios, android

Many phone games restrict the number of turns you can play in a given amount of time. I don't get what is the purpose of this limitation. Is it only to force the player to buy additional turns? Some games don't even allow this for some turn "kinds" (like action A can be played again by spending real money while action B cannot be played again by spending money).

Another possible reason would be to limit the bandwidth usage to their server and make it more predictable over time, but I can't see phone games using so much data.

Comment: It's a combination of encouraging people to spend money buying their virtual currency, and rate limiting players so that the gap between players that don't spend money and those that do doesn't explode out of all proportion. That said, wouldn't this be more suitable on GameDev? It's pretty relevant to game design.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that SE. I think I'm not powerful enough to migrate the question

Comment: @JonK Limits like this also encourage habituation, which keeps people playing (and paying) longer.